# Monitoring a service

Tags: php, performance-monitoring

I have a PHP script that will use `exec` to run commands on the server.  The idea is that it'll monitor a PDF generation script on our server.  I'm running into an issue where when the PDF generation process is stalled it takes up 98% CPU usage and the PHP script doesn't run.  The PHP is supposed to kill the stalled PDF services.

What should I do to resolve this?  What are some other solutions?

Comment: Would it be too much bother to at least tell us what OS?

Answer (score 0):

If you server is running some form of linux, try setting a ulimit on the user that generates the PDF's.